# React propTypes add isRquired to an object whose shape is specified

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a `data` object whose prop types I am validating like this:

```
UserCard.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    phone: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    company: PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
    website: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    address: PropTypes.shape({
      street: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      suite: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      city: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      zipcode: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  }),
};
```

I am using eslint which is throwing this error:

```
propType "data" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration
```

I could add defaultProps for `data` object but is there any way to add isRequired to the data object and avoid the need of having default props altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just going through a blog post on react prop types and deep below in its comments, I found the answer. All that needs to be done is to add `isRequired` after the shape method like this:

```
UserCard.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    phone: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    company: PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
    website: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    address: PropTypes.shape({
      street: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      suite: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      city: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      zipcode: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  }).isRequired,
};
```